# Naming convention for Tabs

Tags: user-expectation, usability-testing, terminology, tabs, user-centered-design

I am working on a tab UI and my goal is to show the remaining number of a particular entity left. The first image is what I got in the first iteration. I tried a different variation in the second image but I am not very sure if it conveys the idea. 
[image: first image]
[image: second image]

Is it a good way to show it in this format (second image)?

Is this good UX (second image)?

Will there be any problem in the future(second image)?

Thankyou in advance

Comment: Seeing the second image without any more context could look like a rating (or steps, or others) rather than items left. Does the context make it clear that the numbers refer to items left?

Comment: Thank you for answering. 
Q: "Does the context make it clear that the numbers refer to items left?" 
A:  I find it clear but many weren't satisfied with view. Thanks for coming up with your view.

Comment: no problem :) If a significant number of users didn't find it clear then possibly it needs to be indicated. If you could share the whole screen maybe we could try to give feedback more relevant to the specific case.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of showing **remaining items** in the tab, you can show **available items**. So, this will be like under potato tab only 5 items are available.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpxDMj.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

I think this would simplify your thought and also user can easily connect to it.

Comment: Thank you for coming up with the mock. 
But is it a good practice to show a variable entity near a stable field?

Comment: It totally depends on your context of design. If your design has something which changes frequently or has something which has to get noticed then inform it through notification of some subtle animation by which user will get to know the update.